# Elasticsearch highlighting with wildcard does not work as expected

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, highlight

I am using elasticsearch highlight for sometime now and having some problems.
here is the highlight query:

```
"highlight" : {
"pre_tags" : [ "<span class=\"mark\">" ],
"post_tags" : [ "</span>" ],
"order" : "score",
"encoder" : "html",
"require_field_match" : false,
"fields" : {
  "*" : { }
}
```

}

I am specifying * in fields because I need highlighting for all possible fields and do not want to specify them all.
The problem is it that if I use field query it highlights also fields that were not queried, 
For example if I query for:

```
Name:Macdonalds
```

It will highlight also:

```
Name:**Macdonalds**
Description: **macdonalds** fast food...
```

I am using query_string query, and I cannot set require_field_match to true since I am also searching free test in all fields and if I set this parameter to true it does not highlight anything...

Any suggestions?
Has someone stumble on such issue?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Will - answered below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have managed to workaround this issue (following @Will comment)
When specifying explicitly all fields you want highlighting on in the query itself and setting `require_field_match" : true`
The highlight works as expected :)
a little strange... but works. This way it has an issue highlighting fields that are not strings, so pay attention.

```
 {
      "from" : 0,
      "size" : 10,
      "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "some query",
          "fields" : [ "field1", "field2", ... ],
          "use_dis_max" : true
        }
      },
      "highlight" : {
        "pre_tags" : [ "<span class=\"mark\">" ],
        "post_tags" : [ "</span>" ],
        "order" : "score",
        "encoder" : "html",
        "require_field_match" : true,
        "fields" : {
          "*" : { }
        }
      }
    }
```